# Merge two bar charts in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two bar charts which is perfectly working good. But i want the merged chart to be sorted and also eliminate the duplicates in the hue.

Below is the chart I got using the code,

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    f = pyplot.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    palette = ["#fee090", "#fdae61", "#4575b4", "#313695", "#e0f3f8", "#abd9e9", "#d73027", "#a50026", "#fee090"]

    bar1 = sb.barplot(x='start_date',  y='total_pcs', hue='process', data=df, palette=palette)
    bar2 = sb.barplot(x='end_date', y='total_pcs', hue='process', data=df, palette=palette)

    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('total_pcs')
```

[image]

I the first chart **bar1** I am getting start_date from the dataframe and in the second chart **bar2** I am getting end_date from the dataframe

But i have the values in start_date - 2023-12-01, 2023-12-02, 2023-12-10

In the end_date - 2023-12-03, 2023-12-20

The chart gets displayed as is in the data set. Is there a way to sort the bars to get the results combining start_date and end_date in a sorted order. 2023-12-01, 2023-12-02, 2023-12-03, 2023-12-10, 2023-12-20. Also to remove the duplicates from the hue.